# Images not rendering with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: html, reactjs

React 15.6.2 (I know, that's where we are for now).

I'm trying to render an html page using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` (it's sourced from our server, no user input). It's working, except images aren't rendering - I just get the broken image icon. There are no errors or warnings in the console. Same problem on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Here's the test html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
img {
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<h1 align="center">Test page</h1><br/>

<img src="images/help-feature_main-menu.jpeg" alt="main menu" style="vertical-align:middle"/><br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the code to render the page

```
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/assets/getting_started/index.html')
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status >= 400) {
          throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`);
        }
        return response.text();
      })
      .then(html => this.setState({ html: html }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Segment>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.state.html }} className="html-import" />
        </Segment>
    );
  }
```

I've tried the path for `fetch` in different forms, including putting the image files in the same dir as the source file.
I've checked the contents of `this.state.html` and it looks good, i.e. the img tag is in there looking right.

If I render the page in an iframe like below, it works correctly with the images. But I don't want to do this because I end up with a scrollbar for both the iframe and the browser window, which is awkward, or if I mess with the height prop of the iframe's container (e.g. height: 70vh), I can get it sized within the window so there's no window scrollbar, but at different heights the iframe will still start to cut off, or it ends up looking too small for the height of the window.

```
<div className="html-iframe-container">
  <iframe src="/assets/getting_started/index.html"</iframe>
</div>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: "`<h1 align="center">`" - sorry, but what year is it?

Comment: Are your photos in the public folder?

Comment: @Dai It's 2021 and the data curator on the project is creating the html docs for the site in Word. Oh well.

Comment: @İbrahimAkar Yes they are in the public folder, in the `images` subfolder of the `index.html` file. I've also tried using the full path to the files, and if I render the file using an `iframe` like described at the end of my post, the images load, so it's not a path or permissions issue.